# Media player not playing mp3 on Android API 28

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to build a dictionary app . and dictionary api provide me the url for the mp3 file. I am using this code to play the mp3 .

This works in all the versions of android except the API 28.

What happens in API 28 is 
- It lake more than 2 minute to hit the setOnPreparedListener (not every time)
- then goes to setOnCompletionListener with out any sound.

Any suggestions about what went wrong is highly appreciated.

```
     mediaPlayer?.apply {
            if(isPlaying){
                return
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                var builder = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                builder.setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                builder.setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
                setAudioAttributes(builder.build())
            }
            setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this@WordHomeVM)
            setOnCompletionListener(this@WordHomeVM)
            setDataSource(urlString)
            setOnPreparedListener { mPlayer ->
                if (!isPlaying) {
                    start()
                }
            }
            prepareAsync()
        }
```

and Here is the only relevant log I get.

```
    2018-12-04 13:22:58.241 5772-5911/ E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
    2018-12-04 13:22:58.247 5772-5772/E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Answer (score 5):

You may meet media player error when playing http live streaming on Android 9 (API 28)

2019-05-14 19:05:31.671 9198-9214/com.xxx.sample E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
2019-05-14 19:05:31.672 9198-9198/com.xxx.sample E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config?hl=en-us

The default configuration for apps targeting Android 9 (API level 28) and higher is as follows:

```
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
```

The default configuration for apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) to Android 8.1 (API level 27) is as follows:

```
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
```

The default configuration for apps targeting Android 6.0 (API level 23) and lower is as follows:

```
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
        <certificates src="user" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
```

So if you want to play http live straming on API 28, you should change your network configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>

<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahh.. I found out the reason after spending quite a bit of time.

The problem was, starting with Android 9.0 (API level 28), cleartext http traffic support is disabled by default.

and [this code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-network-security-config/index.html#3) helped.